# How can I revert the appearance of the close, minimize and zoom buttons with iTunes 10?

Tags: macos, itunes

The new vertical layout is causing me all sorts of grief - is there any way to revert this back to the normal horizontal orientation of the close, minimize and zoom buttons of every other Mac OS X window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do this on Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes full-window -int -1
```

Comment: I would +1 this a million times over if I could.

Comment: Alternatively it's `-boolean YES`. [;-)](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/148631)

Comment: How do you change it back to vertical? And will his work on other programs?

Comment: I don't test it, but have you try : defaults write com.apple.iTunes full-window -int -0     ?

Comment: @Moshe: Yes changing it to -int 0 or -boolean NO will revert it.